# Также — слитно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, также

"А также вести прием не только лично, но и при помощи своих заместителей".

Answer (score 1):

Контекст недостаточен. Иногда написание этого "так()же" предопределяет смысл высказывания.

*Депутат должен посещать заседания Госдумы и участвовать в работе комитетов, **а также** вести прием не только лично, но и при помощи своих заместителей.*

*Депутат должен не просто оперативно решать вопросы, досконально разбираться в законах и ответственно участвовать в работе фракции, **а так же** вести прием не только лично, но и при помощи своих заместителей.*

Имеется в виду **так же** оперативно, досконально и ответственно.

Первый вариант куда более вероятен в реальном тексте, но наверняка всё равно сказать нельзя. Не зря у Розенталя есть оговорка про "необходимость различать".

Comment: Чиновникам всех уравнений необходимо активнее отрабатывать обращения граждан, а также вести прием не только лично, но и при помощи своих заместителей.

Comment: Ну здесь-то однозначно слитно.

Answer (score 0):

Также, а также ― **присоединительные союзы** со слитным написанием (используются в предложениях с однородными членами или в сложных предложениях).

Союзы **надо отличать** от сочетания местоимения и усилительной частицы "так же", например: сегодня **так** же холодно, **как** вчера.

Comment: можно заменить союзом тоже, если заменяется, то пишется слитно...

Comment: В Вашем случае такую замену сделать нельзя,  но вообще являются синонимами союзы ТАКЖЕ, ТОЖЕ, И: он тоже пришел, он также пришел, и он пришел. Замена синонимом - один из способов проверки союзов; при раздельном написании сочетания для проверки можно убрать или переставить частицу ЖЕ

Comment: а так вести прием не только лично, но и при помощи заместителей....вроде подходит без "же"

Comment: Мне кажется, что нет. Без частицы ЖЕ возможен, к примеру, такой вариант: Нужно внимательно работать с каждым посетителем, так  же вести прием нельзя (=  а так вести прием нельзя).